# Уместен ли в предложении "имущественный ценз"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Это изначально группы детей, объединённые не **имущественным цензом**
>   или местом проживания, но искренним интересом к некоему процессу.

(Речь о секциях и кружк*а*х.)

Comment: Если ценз, то видимо, объединяемый должен был владеть игрушкой, а то и двумя? Или объединялись группы с коллективным имуществом?

Comment: Саша, не понимаю. Расскажите в ответе, почему и чем плох имущественный ценз.

Comment: "Ценз" в моём понимании - минимальное требование к имуществу для объединяющихся. Обычно это ограничение при установлении какого-то права.

Comment: Ой-ё! На что поменять-то? О_о

Comment: Объединённые "не общими имущественными интересами" или "не по признаку имущественного равенства" - смотря что имеет в виду автор. Возможно, он имел в виду и достаточную для кружковой деятельности имущественную базу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имущественный ценз (англ. property qualification) — ограничение в правах людей, имущество (или доход) которых меньше некоторой определённой величины ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7))

Термин в данном контексте совершенно неуместный.

"По признаку имущественного равенства" — корректно, но тяжеловато для описания отношений между детьми.

Мое предложение: "по уровню достатка", или "уровнем достатка", или "имущественным уровнем"

И лучше употребить "по" (объединены по какому-то признаку, а не этот признак их объединил - тут преувеличена роль этого признака)

Это изначально группы детей, объединённые не по уровню достатка или по месту проживания, но искренним интересом к некоему процессу.